# Numbers of divisors for a Mersenne number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function, mersenne-numbers

Recently I encountered a problem:

> If n is a positive integer, then is the number of divisors of $2^n - 1$ less or greater than the number of divisors of n?

I tried factoring and taking modulo n but came to no conclusions about this. Does anyone know the answer to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have $m\mid n\implies 2^m-1\mid 2^n-1$ hence the number of divisors of $2^n-1$ is at least the number of divisors of $n$ , usually $2^n-1$ will have more divisors than $n$

Comment: Why not post this as an answer?